# Does App Actions support other non-English locale

Tags: android, app-actions

Is it possible that user invokes specific task of my android app in Chinese via App Actions?
In Google Assistant develop [doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature) it lists locale support for each BII and there is no zh-tw.
But running action in Adidas Running app, which implements App Actions, can be invoked in Chinese via Google Assistant. How to do that?
Because App Actions test tool only supports en locale, I don't know how to check this question before publishing the product.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/languages-locales

Comment: Hi @ShivamYadav  So I have to build actions on Actions Console instead of implementing BII with App Actions? App Actions is easy to implement. It just needs to define action in app's actions.xml. If it supports non-english locale, that will be excellent.

Comment: that is not possible with Built-In Intent you need to do this with dialog flow or define your actions on the console. Right now Built-in intents are very limited and google is working on it.

Comment: @ShivamYadav Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. All locales are listed for each BII under the [reference page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents). Only the ones included on that are currently supported. Please stay tuned for new locales support.